# Record and playback sound in AAC format

Tags: iphone, objective-c, avfoundation, avaudioplayer, avaudiorecorder

I'm trying to record a sound using iPhone microphone and playing it on speakers (or headphones if they are plugged in).

Currently I use this settings and audio playback works... though it doesn't playback on the bottom (loud) speakers of the phone, instead it plays on the ear speaker near the front camera:

```
NSString *tempDir = NSTemporaryDirectory();
NSString *soundFilePath = [tempDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sound.caf"];
NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

NSDictionary *recordSettings = @{AVEncoderAudioQualityKey:  [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMin],
                                 AVEncoderBitRateKey:       @16,
                                 AVNumberOfChannelsKey:     @2,
                                 AVSampleRateKey:           @44100.0};

NSError *error = nil;
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:nil];
_audioRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:soundFileURL settings:recordSettings error:&error];
```

I tried something like this: (changed file extension and added AVFormatIDKey to settings)

```
NSString *soundFilePath = [tempDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sound.aac"];
NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

// Set settings for audio recording
NSDictionary *recordSettings = @{AVFormatIDKey:             [NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC],
                                 AVEncoderAudioQualityKey:  [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMin],
                                 AVEncoderBitRateKey:       @16,
                                 AVNumberOfChannelsKey:     @2,
                                 AVSampleRateKey:           @44100.0};
```

But then I get:

```
Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 2003334207.)
```

If I change the file name extension to .caf it doesn't report errors but it doesn't playback anything.

This is the playback code:

```
NSError *error;
_audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:_audioRecorder.url error:&error];
_audioPlayer.delegate = self;
if (error)  NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
else        [_audioPlayer play];
```

In short, how do I record and playback aac file using iPhone speaker (or headphones if plugged in)?

------------------ EDIT -----------------

Made it save to .aac file by using this settings:

```
NSDictionary *recordSettings = @{AVFormatIDKey: @(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),
        AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: @(AVAudioQualityMin),
        AVSampleRateKey: @16000.0,
        AVNumberOfChannelsKey: @1};
```

Now I just need to playback on the speakers so the user can actually hear what is recorded